# DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147014836 on latest Insider build

Tags: windows-10, uwp

A few days ago was an update for Windows Phone 10 and now I'm unable to deploy my apps to my phone. I keep getting the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147014836 ArduinoBot
```

I am on build 10.0.14356.1000

I tried the `net start IpOverUsbSvc` command but it is already running

Comment: same problem here. quite annoying!

Comment: I believe you have to match the SDK to compile your application with the OS version for the Insider Previews. The Preview SDK is available from the [developer section on Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/).

Comment: you get a timeout: WSAETIMEDOUT - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established respond.

Comment: I resetted my phone, installed the latest SDK, and set my project to target that SDK but it still fails

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the same Windows 10 Mobile build, having the same errore code

Comment: It seems like a big issue in this Insider version. I wish Microsoft would write a public post on their blog about this, it seems quite serious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build  10.0.1436**7** On Phone solves the problem. Released Jun 16 2016

Comment: I'm using build 14385 and still getting the same error.

Comment: So this issue is due to O.S Build target? I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the latest Windows 10 insider builds for Phone and a fix has already been submitted. You should be able to get this scenario working again by moving to the next insider build (what exact build number is still not known).

Comment: Unlucky, even the new build `10.0.14361.0` is still affected by this bug

Comment: I'm in **10.0.14366** it is still affected by this bug

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to generate an .appx package and upload it using the Device Portal. You can activate the Device Portal on the phone from Settings -> "For developers".